# method for creating a single index metric representative of multiple complex dynamic metrics

Tags: statistics

I am trying to create a index metric of multiple metric to show a representative score for a specific category.

example: In the datacenter, there are multiple components such as compute, storage, power, space, network, firewalls

each of these have multiple NODES and associated metrics like usage, performance, health, number of xxx processed etc. and these metrics are over time.

Another example: Developers have multiple activities, like checkin, number of line modified, bug fixed per checkin, bugs, failed regression

Is there a mathematical model that can take these metrics & some additional configurations like importance, relevance and create a single score that I can track over time - and then if I wish to double click to understand blips on the graph, I can look at it by looking at the individual metrics ?

We have ELK stack collecting all this datacenter data and other ITSMC tools that have support metrics, SLA etc.

are there any applications that do this ? sort of like the tracker of S&P500 or FINTECH stocks etc. like the index fund that tracks multiple types of stocks based on invested $$.

thanks

Comment: I'm not seeing a specification that gives a basis for reasoned mathematical argument.  In many respects you seem to be asking for a software recommendation, not help with learning math.

Comment: if there is a mathematical model I can apply, please do share as well. I am sure I can learn from that - and programmatically approach this. I just don't want to do some averages and claim it works.. I am looking for options

Comment: The broad sweep of your Question is informed only by two very generalized examples.  You "don't want to do some averages and claim it works," but you haven't conveyed what the consequences of working or not working are.  A narrower formulation of the problem is in order.